# Не запускается отладка проекта CMake

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, ssh

Возникает ошибка, при удалённой отладке:

`Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?`

Отдельно проект запускается на удалёнке. GTK стоит.
Пробовал использовать:

`ssh -X host@name` `ssh -YC host@name`

менять настройки в конфиг файлах ssh - X11Forwarding yes

`xhost +host@name` добавлял

, но от ошибки так и не избавился. Как её решить?

Comment: никак не раскрыто отношение к вопросу следующих программ: linux, cmake и visual studio.

Comment: DISPLAY=:0 или типа того где-то надо сделать вроде. Типа `DISPLAY=:0 ssh -X host@name`. Не помню, но ругается на это (явно): `is DISPLAY set properly?`

Comment: @vegorov, спасибо за комментарий, но в моём случае, это не помогло.